# Console error: Element type is invalid:expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React here and stuck with console errors:
Here's the code I have used. This is a simple to-do list app.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

app.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import {Row, Col, Button, InputGroup, FormControl, ListGroup} from "react-bootstrap";

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput : "",
      list: []
    }
  }

  updateInput(value){
    this.setState({
     userInput: value,
    });
  }

  addItem(){
    if(this.state.userInput !== " "){
      const userInput = {
        id: Math.random(),
        value: this.state.userInput
      };

      const list = [...this.state.list];
      list.push(userInput);
      this.setState({
        list,
        userInput: ""
      })
    } 
  }

  deleteItem(key){
    const  list = [...this.state.list];
    const UpdateList = list.filter(item => item.id !== key);
    this.setState({
      list:UpdateList,
    });
  }

  render(){
    return( <Container>
      <Row style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        fontSize: "3rem",
        fontWeight: "bolder",
      }}
      >To Do List</Row>
      <hr/>

      <Row>
        <Col md={{ span: 5, offset: 4}}>
          <InputGroup className= "mb-3">
            <FormControl
              placeholder= "Add Task"
              size= "lg"
              value= {this.state.userInput}
              onChange = {item => this.updateInput(item.target.value)}
              aria-label="Add something"
              aria-describedby= "basic-addon2"
            />
            <InputGroup.Append>
              <Button
                variant="dark"
                size= "lg"
                onClick = {() => this.addItem()}
              >ADD</Button>
            </InputGroup.Append>
          </InputGroup>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row>
        <Col md= {{  span: 5, offset: 4}}>
          <ListGroup>
            {}
            {this.state.list.map(item => {return(
              <ListGroup.Item variant="dark" action
                onClick = { () => this.deleteItem(item.id) }>
                {item.value}
              </ListGroup.Item>
            )})}
          </ListGroup>
          </  Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

My understanding is that it has something to do with imports but not entirely sure what's causing it. Have tried replacing the third line in app.js with individual imports like import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col",
but still I am getting the same error.
[image: Console error logs]

Comment: There isn't a component as `Append` on `InputGroup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First React doesn't like the way you are importing the Container component.

```
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
```

Import it like you are importing line 3 of the app.

```
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
```

Second error: There is no InputGroup.Append component in bootstrap as far as I can see and that is what is causing the problem. Try removing it and run.

```
 <InputGroup.Append>
          <Button
            variant="dark"
            size= "lg"
            onClick = {() => this.addItem()}
          >ADD</Button>
 </InputGroup.Append>
```

For Examples This works. Without the .Append

```
 <InputGroup>
          <Button
            variant="dark"
            size= "lg"
            onClick = {() => this.addItem()}
          >ADD</Button>
</InputGroup>
```

Hope, that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error is with  `<InputGroup.Append>` seems the `append` is not available , if you remove it , it should be working fine.

```
<Button variant="dark" size="lg"
    onClick={() => this.addItem()}>
                ADD
  </Button>
```

Comment: Yup, tried commenting it and it worked. Any ideas on why the method is not available?

Comment: may be you can try looking at the docs [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/input-group/)